# OS StreetView SO

Tags: qgis, labeling

Is it possible to remove or hide the road names that are shown using the StreetView plugin? Therefore all I want to see are the actual roads but no names/labels etc. Can this possibly be done?

I am using QGIS version 2.12.1-Lyon. I am using the OS StreetView layer. I have attached a screen grab of one section of the map. What I am trying to do is remove or hide the road names, for example on this screen grab where it says VAGA CRESCENT, OAKLANDS, RIVER VIEW etc. I want to get rid of these labels/road names. So the map will show the roads but no name.

[image]

Comment: I can't see a plugin called StreetView that offers OS StreetView Data??

Comment: Or generate vector tiles with OpenData Vector District https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html and use the QGIS Style sheets (saving hours) https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/blog/2013/02/style-sheets-available-for-all-our-vector-products/ https://github.com/OrdnanceSurvey/OS-VectorMap-Local-stylesheets/tree/master/GML%20stylesheets

Answer (score 1):

This layer is a WMS which cannot be manipulated by end-users (removing street labels) in QGIS.  Some providers of these services do have their own APIs/maps which you may use to change the styling and labeling outside of QGIS (e.g. Google maps).

Answer (score 1):

Ordnance Survey StreetView map tiles come with world files (*.tfw files) so in theory it would be possible to edit them with a graphics editor to remove the street names without destroying their georeferencing (as long as you don't change the scale, size or resolution of the images in the process).

In practice you would almost certainly be better off downloading the OS Open Map Local vector dataset and styling this using the appropriate style files, also supplied by the OS.